# Float right div over left div

Tags: html, css

As you can see bottom I've two div inline/columbs (one-half - left of page, one half last - right of page). My goal is to float the 2° div (one half last) over the first when the page is resized.

Basically I want that the 1° div collapse under the 2°. Is there a way to do this?

The trouble is that I can only obtain the float left of 2° div under the 1°.

Advices?

```
<div>
    <div class="one-half">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p style="text-align: justify;">Text</p>
    <p style="text-align: justify;">Text.</p>
        <p style="text-align: justify;">Text.</p>
</div>
<div class="one-half last">
   <img src="#" class="shadow" alt="#" style="max-width: 455px;width: 100%;">
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

---

```
.one-half { 
   width: 460px;
}

.last { 
   float: left;
}
```

Comment: Use a z-index attribute?

Comment: At first, change `one-half` and `one-half last` in your CSS to `.one-half` and `.last`. You're missing the dot to select a class. Also the second rule is selecting `.last` as a child of `.one-half`, but actually it's the same element.

Comment: ... and remove the space between one-half and last

Comment: Yes, sorry for mistakes but ignore this CSS. In my site is a default class usefull to put div inline. I just try with Z-index but it's useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Pure css and html way :** 
for page resize detection, use media queries

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 600px) {
.one-half {
        display: none;
    }

    .last {
        float: left;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

considering the comment, update css to

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 600px) {
.one-half {
        float:left; 
    }

    .last {
        float: left;
        clear: left;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank's for reply. It isn't a problem of page resize. The div in the right of page must float over the div in the left of page.

Comment: so you want the right div to place above left div vertically??

Comment: WORKS. I changed the image position putting it first without any div and adding clear propriety as you suggest. Now all is working perfectly. Thank you very much.